# Nylon or steel strings

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I have just bought myself an old acoustic guitar to learn to play. It's a'Kiso Suzuki 9502' It is presently strung with steel strings but is this correct? 
  Regards, Marty.

Comment: Yeah, you probably should have passed on this purchase but may work out. That is a nice old guitar. Take the steel strings off immediately and do not ever put on steel strings again. That is a classical and should only have nylon strings.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not put steel strings on a classical guitar.**

The construction of a classical guitar is not engineered to withstand the tension required for steel strings.  Steel strings can have two times the tension than nylon, and the additional tension will eventually pull off the bridge and cause warping, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If my google image search is correct, the "Kiso Suzuki 9502" is a classical guitar which means it has to be strung with nylon strings. However, it could be that what you assume to be steel strings is simply nylon wound with metal, in which case your guitar is already strung with nylon strings.